# How to extract number from string c#

Tags: c#

I have a string

```
"transform(23, 45)"
```

from this string i have to extract 23 and 45, i did

```
var xy = "transform(23,45)".Substring("transform(23,45)".indexOf('(') + 1).TrimEnd(')');
var num = xy.Split(',');
```

I am using c#. Is there any better method to do this in c#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression:

```
string sInput = "transform(23, 45)";
Match match = Regex.Match(sInput, @"(\d)+",
              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    foreach (var sVal in match)
             // Do something with sVal
}
```

You can read more on Regular Expressions [here](http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/csharp-regular-expressions.html).
Use [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) for training, it helps alot!

Answer (score 2):

Well, a simply regular expression string would be `([0-9]+)`, but you may need to define other expression constraints, e.g., what are you doing to handle periods, commas, etc in strings?

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("transform(23,45)", "([0-9]+)");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{  
    int value = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    // Do work.
}
```

Comment: +1 for "periods, commas, etc...", and to add to the list: non-10-base number literals, forced type literals ([VB examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek(v=vs.80).aspx), but other programming languages have them as well), etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
string[] t = "transform(23, 45)".ToLower().Replace("transform(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty).Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Regex`:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"(\d+)");
```

explain:

```
\d    Matches any decimal digit.

\d+   Matches digits (0-9) 
      (1 or more times, matching the most amount possible)
```

and for using:

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{  
    var number = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```